# Using gtest to write tests with more than one template parameter

Tags: googletest

I'm familiar with writing tests for multiple different classes by using typed tests. Is it possible to write a typed test where each test has more than one type parameter?

Comment: I did not understand you question. Add more details so we can help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parameterize your test on a pair or tuple of desired types.